# PHP export JSON to CSV

Tags: php, json, csv

Im try export json result to csv and save data as file, im try with something like this

```
$getFile = file_get_contents('JSON_URL');
$json_obj = json_decode($getFile);
$fp = fopen('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/api/export/tmp/file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($json_obj as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
fclose($fp);
```

but seems not working

Here's an example json format for link above

```
[
    {key:value,key:value...}
...]
```

Comment: What is happening when you do that? And what did you expect to happen?

Comment: in what way is it not working? are you getting any errors? is it creating a file at all? is it creating it empty, or with incorrect data? or mis-formatted?

Comment: Just get error in error_log `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` , im change title of post, i need to export data to CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order for your code to work as expected, try decoding the json object as an associative array. This is done by passing a boolean `true` to the 2nd param of `json_decode`

```
$json_obj = json_decode($getFile, true);
```

Comment: could you point me at a way to do this if the JSON is being posted to the PHP through a form? I am not a PHP dev but am trying to cobble this together through scraps of code.